# Getting different values from multiple buttons

Tags: php, html

I am using php and html. I have two buttons in my table as shown in the image bellow. When I press the `Update` button, it displayed the correct `name` and `value` properties of the Update button. However, when I press the `jan_data` button, it doesn't show the properties of that button. Instead it shows the `name` and `value` properties of the Description text box. I am new to html and can you please tell me what modifications I should do to get the correct value of the `jan_data` button when I click it. (not allowed to use JavaScript in my website).

```
<?php
echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">
<table border=\"1\"><tbody>
<tr>
<td>January:</td>
<td><input id=\"WorkOrder1\" type=\"text\" name=\"val1\" value=\"$\" /><input type=\"submit\" name=\"january_box\" value=\"jan_data\" /></td>
<td>february:</td>
<td><input id=\"WorkOrder2\" type=\"text\" name=\"val2\" value=\"$\" /></td>
<td>March:</td>
<td><input id=\"WorkOrder3\" type=\"text\" name=\"val3\" value=\"$\" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>April:</td>
<td><input id=\"WorkOrder4\" type=\"text\" name=\"val4\" value=\"$\" /></td>
<td>May:</td>
<td><input id=\"WorkOrder5\" type=\"text\" name=\"val5\" value=\"$\" /></td>
<td>June:</td>
<td><input id=\"WorkOrder6\" type=\"text\" name=\"val6\" value=\"$\" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description:</td>
<td colspan=\"5\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"description_box\" value=\"description_data\" size=\"44\" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"updatebutton\" value=\"Update\" /></form>";


foreach($_POST as $key => $value){} //Only needs to find which button is pressed    
    echo "<br>key is: $key<br>";
    echo "value is: $value<br>";
?>
```

[image]

Comment: The ``echo statements`` are out of the ``forEach block``, please see the ``{}``

Comment: For the sanity of others, please consider to use `echo` only for smaller pieces of HTML; use `?><html><?php` for bigger chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){}
    echo "<br>key is: $key<br>";
    echo "value is: $value<br>";
```

To:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo "<br>key is: $key<br>";
    echo "value is: $value<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this doesn't solve my problem. it will give `key` and `value` of all the text boxes and buttons. I only wants to get the value of the button some one clicks.

Comment: Look for the ``value`` of both the buttons, the one clicked will be set and the other one will be ''

Comment: ok, thanks. my bad. I see the difference now. thanks for all of your comments and the help.